# Trigger ON BEFORE error

Tags: sql, triggers, mariadb, cascading-deletes

I have two tables and would like to create a trigger to delete on ticket_reply when a ticket is deleted:

ticket:

```
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id     | int(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| status      | varchar(6)      | NO   |     | opened  |                |
| subject     | varchar(100)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| message     | text            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And ticket_reply:

```
+-----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id   | int(8) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ticket_id | int(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| message   | text            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `ticket_delete` BEFORE DELETE ON ticket
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM ticket_reply
    WHERE ticket_reply.ticket_id = ticket.id;
END
```

I get the error message: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5`

Why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use delimiters, or skip `BEGIN` / `END` :

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER `ticket_delete` BEFORE DELETE ON ticket
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM ticket_reply
    WHERE ticket_reply.ticket_id = ticket.id;
END $
DELIMITER ;
```

or

```
CREATE TRIGGER `ticket_delete` BEFORE DELETE ON ticket
FOR EACH ROW
DELETE FROM ticket_reply
    WHERE ticket_reply.ticket_id = ticket.id;
```

It will make the syntax error go away; but your trigger is wrong, in fact it should be

```
CREATE TRIGGER `ticket_delete` BEFORE DELETE ON ticket
FOR EACH ROW
DELETE FROM ticket_reply
    WHERE ticket_reply.ticket_id = OLD.id;
```

(notice `OLD.id` instead of `ticket.id`).

Comment: Yes indeed, it was not working and now it's working fine with `OLD.id`. It was my first Trigger :) I thought I wouldn't need `OLD.id` because I am using `BEFORE DELETE ON` and not `AFTER DELETE ON `